# Why does Map with Arrays as keys does not work?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set([2,2], 4);
```

I would expect for `map.get([2,2])` to return `4`, but for some reason it returns `undefined`

Comment: If you define `key = [2, 2]` and use `map.set(key)`, you can use `map.get(key)` to get the value back. See marked duplicate for more info.

Comment: `let map = new Map();
let key = [2, 2];
map.set(key, 4);`

Comment: The basic problem is that Map keys are checked for *reference* equality and not *value* equality.  So if the array you use to set the value and the one you use the test the value refer to the same place in memory, it will work as you hope.  If you can't do that, then `Map` is not going to work, and you might look into a library that uses value equality.   If, however, you're always using arrays of numbers for keys, then you could use `JSON.stringify` on them before setting or testing, and it should help.